# Wordpress theme does not work online

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, localhost

I have installed wordpress and a theme, customized that on my localhost.

Everything is ok on that pc where xampp is installed.

But if I go to that page (on the same network) from another pc - I see no css, no style, just messy text.

Even when I move it to the live server I get the same mess.

Anyone could tell me why?

Comment: What's URL of wordpress in Settings ? 
When you access from another PC, what URL you enter & is that the same URL that's set in Wordpress General settings ?

Comment: where wordpress installed I use localhost/sitename and on other pc I use first ones IP adress. 192.168...../sitename.

Comment: in general settings WordPress Address (URL) same as  site address: http://localhost/sitename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Wordpress settings. And in URL enter URL with IP address of pc. instead of `localhost/sitename` change it to`192.168.../sitename`

Then access it from other pc using same address like `192.168.../sitename`

This will solve the issue hopefully.

Comment: it seems  like it helped. thanks. what about live server? I have already uploaded to server all source. how and to what address do I change in general settings? if I go to wp-admin it goes to http://localhost/sitename/wp-login.php? and of course page does not exist on server.

Comment: Just update URL fields when you have uploaded all files and site on server & please Accept the answer.